# what does [...] mean as an output in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying set ships on a Battleship board. The function in the code below should do this with a number of ships and an board (an array of arrays) as arguments. When I run this in Terminal, I get:

```
[[1, [...]], [1, [...]], [2, [...]]]
```

What does [...] mean? How to replace [...] with a random integer from 0 to 2 in this output?

```
from random import randint

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)
def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)
def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

def set_the_ships(num_ships,board):
    ship_list = []
    for i in range(num_ships):
        ship_row = random_row(board)
        ship_col = random_col(board)    
        position = [ship_row,ship_list]
        for j in range(i - 1):
            while (position[0] == ship_list[j][0] and position[1] == ship_list[j][1]):
                ship_row = random_row(board)
                ship_col = random_col(board)    
                position = [ship_row,ship_list]
        ship_list.append(position)
    return ship_list

print set_the_ships(3,[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`...` means, there's reference cycle.

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.append(l)
>>> l
[[...]]
```

Comment: By "reference cycle" he means that the list contains a reference to itself.

Comment: Not only to itself, but to any object already being printed inside the recursive call, consider for example: `a=[]; b=[a]; a.append(b); c=[a]; print c`

Answer (score 2):

See this line:

```
position = [ship_row,ship_list]
```

This should be

```
position = [ship_row,ship_col]
```

(Same when you re-assign `position in the`while` loop)

Later, when you do `ship_list.append(position)`, this causes `ship_list` to be nested in itself, which Python prints as `[...]`.